# Update a record by taking an id from the url

Tags: php

Hello everyone i'm taking a value from a URL by get and pass it into an update statement, when i put WHERE ID= 1 , it work fine but when i put the ID=$id, the code work but there is no update, the record remain the same, can some help me to resolve this problem please

```
   <?php
   require 'db2.php';
    $id = null;
   if ( !empty($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];

 $dbc = mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) OR die ('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error() );
    $q = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM movie WHERE MovieID = '$id' ");
   while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($q))
   {   
    $title = $r["Title"];
    $tag = $r["Tag"];
    $year = $r["YEAR"];
    $cast = $r["Cast"];
    $comment = $r["Comment"];
    $IDBM = $r["IMDB"];
  }


  }


 if (!empty($_POST) ) {
 if ( !empty($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];

    // keep track post values
    $cast = $_POST['cast'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $comment =$_POST['comment'];
     $year = $_POST['year'];
      $tag = $_POST['tags'];
       $IDBM = $_POST['idbm'];
    $cast = htmlspecialchars($cast);
    $title = htmlspecialchars($title);
    $comment = htmlspecialchars($comment);

    // validate input
    $valid = true;
    if (empty($cast)) {
        $castError = 'Please enter Cast';
        $valid = false;
    }

    if (empty($title)) {
        $titleError = 'Please enter Title';
        $valid = false;
    }
      if (empty($comment)) {
        $commentError = 'Please enter Comment';
        $valid = false;
    }


    if ($valid) {

    $path = "uploads/";



$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp");
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
    {
        $name = $_FILES['photoimg']['name'];
        $size = $_FILES['photoimg']['size'];

        if(strlen($name))
            {
                list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
                if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
                {
                if($size<(1024*1024))
                    {
                        $actual_image_name = time().substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $txt), 5).".".$ext;
                        $tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];
                        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name))
                            {

                                mysqli_query($dbc,"UPDATE movie SET Title='$title',Year = '$year',Cast='$cast',Cover='$actual_image_name',Tag='$tag',Comment='$comment',IMDB ='$IDBM' WHERE MovieID=".$id);
                                header ("Location: index.php");
                            }
                        else
                            echo "failed";
                    }
                    else
                    echo "Image file size max 1 MB";                    
                    }
                    else
                    echo "Invalid file format..";   
            }

        else
            echo "Please select image..!";

        exit;
    }


    }
    }
    echo"error";
    }
```

Comment: have you checked what is the query that is executin

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). And have you confirmed that your `$_GET['id']` is what you think it is? `example.com?ID=foo` and `example.com?id=foo` are two entirely different query strings as far as php is concerned.

Comment: "WHERE ID= 1 works" OK so why do you use `WHERE MovieID=` if the field is `ID`? Which is it?

Comment: @MrCode,i'm taking the id from url as query string , that y i'm using a get

Comment: @user790454,i edited the code for a precise understanding can u check please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

> $id = strip_tags(intval($_GET['id']));
>
> mysqli_query($dbc,"UPDATE `movie` SET `Title`='{$title}', `Year` =
>   '{$year}', `Cast`='{$cast}',
>   `Cover`='{$actual_image_name}',`Tag`='{$tag}', `Comment`='{$comment}',
>   `IMDB` ='{$IDBM}' WHERE `MovieID`='{$id}';");

To verify if $id have same value:

> echo $id;

Comment: it is printing the value equal to zero, but in the url i see the value  1

Comment: Your url is: example.com?ID=1 or example.com?id=1 ?

Comment: id = 1, i put all my code on here so that you could help ok

Comment: i have edit the question with all code, can you take a look please

Comment: ok! but when you get or post id: ID=1 (ID is uppercase?) or id=1 ?

Comment: id=1, look at the question, changed it, i put all the code

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like maybe your MovieID isn't defined as an integer but we can't tell for sure because you haven't told us the error message that mysqli_query is throwing.

You need to be checking the error message created by mysqli_query to know.  See http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$id = $_GET['id']; // taking the value from URL 

mysqli_query($dbc,"UPDATE movie SET Title='$title',Year = '$year',Cast='$cast',Cover='$actual_image_name',Tag='$tag',Comment='$comment',IMDB ='$IDBM' WHERE MovieID=".$id); // the sql statement of the query
```

and best you protect the get by using `intval()` to prevent injections

```
 $id = intval($_GET['id']); // taking the value from URL
```